# How to specify a style block in react component?

Tags: reactjs

I'm generating email text using React component. I have a problem with specifying styles for this email. For example in HTML I would specify it as following:

```html
<div id="achievementMail">
  <style>
    #mailContent {
      margin: 10px;
      font-family: "Lato", "Helvetica Neue", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
      font-size: 14px;
      line-height: 1.33;
    }
  </style>
  <div id="mailContent">
    Dear players ... <br/>
  </div>
</div>
```

But, since React does not allow styles and uses object notation, I am not sure how to specify styles that I attach to the email.

Thanks.

Comment: Why exactly do you need a style block? https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/inline-styles.html

Answer (score 7):

JSX does support a style block. This is what it would look like:

```
const Margins = () => {
  return (
    <div className="Class">
      <style>{`
        .Class{
          background: orange;
        }
      `}</style>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Remember, it should be in side a the `return` and

> `style` tag should not be a sibling

Comment: thanks for your answer, would you mind to link the documentation's source?

Comment: put `background-image:url("xxx")` in that and watch it break. jsx will encode the quotations.

Comment: This does work, the issue is that there is no way to validate CSS. Does anyone have a solution to this?

Answer (score 3):

You would need to create the `style` block and set the contents from a variable.

```
render: function () {
    var styles = '#mailContent { margin: 10px; font-family: "Lato", "Helvetica Neue", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 14px; line-height: 1.33; }';
    return (
      <div id="achievementMail">
        <style>
          { styles }
        </style>
        <div id="mailContent">
          Dear players ... <br/>
        </div>
      </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` attribute to add your CSS to a `<style />` tag like this:

```
<style dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
  __html: `
    .yourelement { 
      width:10px;
    }
  `
}} />
```

Comment: A lot of people hate on this method, but its the easiest way for things like:
`background-image:url("xxx")
or 
@media (min-width: 768px) {xxx}`
otherwise jsx will replace the quotes with &quot; which breaks the css, and I have no idea how to do a media query in jsx.